# Using int in try outside of context

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("Write a number: ");

            try
            {
                int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch ( OverflowException )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number to big");
            }

            TellLastNumber(Number);
```

It says the 'Number' does not exist in the current context.
How can I make the int 'Number' used everywhere in the main()?

Comment: Learn about [scope in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/08/12/how-to-keep-a-local-variable-in-scope-across-a-try-and-catch-block.aspx) (the example is way outdated now that we have `using` blocks, but the principle stands).

Answer (score 5):

> How can I make the int 'Number' used everywhere in the main()?

Just move declaration of variable `Number` to the scope of `main()` and it will be available from that point to the end of the function.

```
        Console.Write("Write a number: ");

        int Number = 0;
        try
        {
            Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch ( OverflowException )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number to big");
        }

        TellLastNumber(Number);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the error you have to define the `Number` outside of the try block and assign it some default value.

```
int Number = 0;
try
{
    int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch ( OverflowException )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number to big");
}

TellLastNumber(Number);
```

**But** more importantly use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx), that will not raise an exception if the number passed to it is not an int.

```
int Number;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");   
}
TellLastNumber(Number);
```

You are getting the error, because compiler can't see `Number` outside the scope of `try`.

Comment: +1 for pointing the user to `int.TryParse` with a proper MSDN link.